# Onclick Confirm add Checkbox Length

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, checkbox

This should be really simple, but I can't get it to work and I'm an absolute beginner with Javascript. I looked at various threads here. 
 I'm working with a django template, on a simple link. I want to add an onclick confirmation message such as 'Trash (14) Projects? Are you sure?' where 14 is the number of checkboxes ready to submit in a form. Right now I have.

```
<button type="submit" class="actionbutton" name="delete" onclick="return confirm('Add projects to trash - Are you sure?')" >Remove / Add To Trash</button>
```

Which of course doesn't have the number of projects to be deleted. I could add a script in the head to count the classes of checkboxes, but I want to know how I might execute javascript inside the confirm dialog itself? Such as...

```
<button type="submit" class="actionbutton" name="delete" onclick="return confirm('Add ($(":checkbox:checked").length) to trash - Are you sure?')" >Remove / Add To Trash</button>
```

Which doesn't work, probably because the ":checkbox:checked" gets escaped inside the onclick " ".

Anyone point me in the right direction as to what is the 'usual' way to do this kind of thing...

Comment: Try once with `onclick="return confirm('Add (' + $(':checkbox:checked').length + ') to trash - Are you sure?')"`

Comment: Perfect! I forget the + - Thanks Satpal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes wisely and use `+` to create a valid string

```
<button type="submit" class="actionbutton" name="delete" onclick="return confirm('Add (' + $(':checkbox:checked').length + ') to trash - Are you sure?')" >Remove / Add To Trash</button>
```

---

I would recommend using unobtrusive event handler. Add a unique identifier, I have added `submitbutton` as CSS class

```
<button type="submit" class="actionbutton submitbutton" name="delete" >Remove / Add To Trash</button>
```

Bind event using Native Vanilla JS

```
document.querySelector('.submitbutton').addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var msg = 'Add (' + document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]:checked').length + ') to trash - Are you sure?';
    if (!confirm(msg)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

*jQuery*

```
$('.submitbutton').on('click', function(){
    return confirm('Add (' + $(':checkbox:checked').length + ') to trash - Are you sure?')
});
```

Comment: When you say 'Bind the event' - specific to Django template, how do I execute the code - it doesn't work in script tags...